Need outdoor security lights be waterproof?
I am trying to buy a security light (with replaceable light bulbs) like this or this. However, as you see in the picture, the lightbulbs and the light sockets are exposed to the weather. I am worried that rain or snow can get into the socket on windy days and cause electricity leakage or fire. Is it safe? If not, can anyone help me understand what lights are safe?

I have similar design sockets/bulbs for years with no problem.  If they are UL listed they should be safe.

you only need waterproof to put them under water, weatherproof is enough for outdoors, unless you expect flooding,  the second picture claims "waterproof" but they are lying - this is scamazon after all.

@Jasen Amazon garbage is garbage, but the official terminology for North America is a fixture and bulb that is rated for wet locations.

The lights are outdoor rated so they can be used outdoors. They are used outside in many areas without issue.
Understand with the occasional rain and snow incursion, there may be moisture that gets into the base.  This could cause a GFCI to open or the breaker, however a fire is not likely. With the weather expect the unit to wear at a faster rate than a unit that has protection.

I know it seems kind of cheesy, but usually they come with rubber gaskets that slide over the base of the lamp and into the cone around the screw shell.
I know the product picture show the gasket at the rim of the lampholder, but normally they tuck inside.
